# How Do I install Flake8-SQL plugin and run its rules

Tags: flake8

I installed flake8-SQL but if I failed to run its rules

When I run flake8 I get an error `custom.sql:1:15: E999 SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description, code, errors of your search/research efforts as is suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flake8-sql` doesn't lint `.sql` files directly, it [lints strings in your code that look like sql statements](https://github.com/pgjones/flake8-sql#limitations)

flake8 is based around linting python files, linting other non-python files is out of scope.  You probably want to find a separate tool to lint / format your sql files (asking for tool suggestions is off topic on this site)

---

disclaimer: I'm the current flake8 maintainer